How to add proxy for Clerk auth in Next.js/Vercel app?
I am trying to follow along with these Clerk docs, but they are leaving out some information it seems:

https://clerk.com/docs/advanced-usage/using-proxies

So I have a simple Next.js 14 app, using the app router pattern and app directory. They say you need to add these 3 headers to the proxy:

Clerk-Proxy-Url: Needs to have the full proxy URL.
Clerk-Secret-Key: The secret key for your Clerk instance.
X-Forwarded-For: The IP address of the original client making the request.

So what I did so far is this.... Add the following to layout.tsx:
'use client'

import { ClerkProvider } from '@clerk/nextjs'

export default function AppLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <ClerkProvider proxyUrl="https://example.com/proxy">
      {children}
    </ClerkProvider>
  )
}

FYI, my Next.js app is hosted on Vercel under example.com.
So now we need a handler for that /proxy path, so I tried adding this to next.config.js but it doesn't seem to allow adding headers:
{
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/proxy/*',
        destination: `https://frontend-api.clerk.dev/*`,
      },
    ]
  },
}

So that won't work I don't think. So my next bet is on adding an app/middleware.ts file, which contained this:
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers)
  requestHeaders.append('Clerk-Proxy-Url', 'https://example.com/proxy')
  requestHeaders.append(
    'Clerk-Secret-Key',
    String(process.env.CLERK_SECRET_KEY),
  )

  const url = request.nextUrl.clone()
  url.protocol = 'https'
  url.hostname = 'frontend-api.clerk.dev'
  url.pathname = url.pathname.replace(/^\/proxy/, '')

  return NextResponse.rewrite(url, {
    headers: requestHeaders,
  })
}

export const config = {
  matcher: '/proxy/:path*',
}

I have not yet used Next.js middleware, but adding some console.logs in that middleware function doesn't seem to do anything if I visit /proxy/foo. How do I trigger the proxy request to test?
And I haven't added the X-Forwarded-For header yet, I'm not sure if Next.js already gives you that or if I need to somehow find that from somewhere...
So my question is, how do I wire up the proxy with Clerk in a Next.js/Vercel app? I need to use the proxy so I can brand everything under my domain. The related aspects to this question are:

How do I set the X-Forwarded-For header in the proxy?
Is my middleware idea the correct approach? If not, how can I set headers in the rewrites from Next.js?
Do I need to set the proxyUrl everywhere to either http://localhost:3000/proxy (during development), and https://example.com/proxy in production, or can I leave it as the example.com/proxy URL in both cases? I am not quite sure how to wire this up in dev vs. prod (I am using dev secrets/keys in my .env.local file locally, and I have set the prod env vars in Vercel from the Clerk dashboard already.

The only error I'm currently getting (locally) is Error: Clerk: Failed to load Clerk.

Any help getting this wired up would be fantastic. Clerk looks like it will cut out the need to do a lot of detailed auth work I've had to implement in the past, so I'm excited to get this working!

I needed to put the middleware at the base of the Next.js application, not in the app folder, and I needed to slightly change the way I called the NextResponse.rewrite function, so it's like this:
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers)
  requestHeaders.set('Clerk-Proxy-Url', 'https://example.com/proxy')
  requestHeaders.set(
    'Clerk-Secret-Key',
    String(process.env.CLERK_SECRET_KEY),
  )
  requestHeaders.set('Origin', String(process.env.CLERK_PROXY_ORIGIN))

  const url = request.nextUrl.clone()
  url.protocol = 'https'
  url.hostname = 'frontend-api.clerk.dev'
  url.pathname = url.pathname.replace(/^\/proxy/, '')

  return NextResponse.rewrite(url, {
    request: { headers: requestHeaders },
  })
}

export const config = {
  matcher: '/proxy/:path*',
}

I also had to set the origin header, to match the domain where the request is originating from.
Having deployed that to production, it now works only in production. Next thing I need to figure out is how to get it working from localhost:3000, because I'm getting this error now:

Access to fetch at 'https://example.com/proxy/v1/dev_browser?_clerk_js_version=4.70.6' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://example.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

If you know how to fix this, feel free to leave a comment. But at least generally speaking the proxy is now working, woohoo!

https is hardcoded inside their node module unfortunately

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
